# Html.ActionLink with an Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know of a decent way to cleanly use Html.ActionLink helper with an image instead of text without going through a huge amount of replace scripts and the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="<%= ${Url.Action("myaction") %>"><img src="img.gif"/></a>
```

Comment: That doesn't let me specify anything that the ActionLink helper does, though, like the object to pass through.

Comment: Wait, I see it now. What is the ${ for though?

Comment: Oops, that's my Spark View Engine background; ${} is used instead of <%= %> there ;-)